# Laravel stripe (customers and invoice)

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I created customer and product in stripe.
I create paymentIntent, invoiceItems and invoice for this customer. How i can connect invoice and payment?
My controller:

```
        //check user in stripe
        $stripeCustomer = $this->stripe->customers->search([
            'query' => "email:'$user->email'",
        ]);

        if (isset($stripeCustomer['data']) && !count($stripeCustomer['data']) ) {
            //create new user
            $stripeCustomer = $this->stripe->customers->create([
                'email' => $user->email,
                'name'  => $user->name
            ]);

            $stripeCustomerId = $stripeCustomer->id ?: 0;
        } else {
            $stripeCustomerId = $stripeCustomer['data'][0]->id;
        }

        $invoiceItems = $this->stripe->invoiceItems->create([
            'customer' => $stripeCustomerId,
            'price' => $product ? $product->stripe_price_id : null,
        ]);

        //create draft invoice
        $invoice = $this->stripe->invoices->create([
            'customer' => $stripeCustomerId,
        ]);

        //create payment
        $paymentIntent = $this->stripe->paymentIntents->create([
            'customer' => $stripeCustomerId,
            'amount' => $invoiceItems->amount,
            'currency' => Payment::CURRENCY_EUR,
            'payment_method_types' => ['card']
        ]);

        $clientSecret = $paymentIntent->client_secret;
```

After submitting form (number card, etc...) I am confirmPayment in view:

```
            const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
                elements,
                confirmParams: {
                    // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
                    return_url: "{{route('payment-success'), [ 'token' => $token ])}}",
                },
            });
```

My paymentSuccess method:

```
public function paymentSuccess($token)
    {
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode($token));
    //$data->paymentId
    // maybe here i must pay invoice  for my paymentId???

    
}
```

Comment: Stripe ```invoice``` and ```payment``` both are different things why are you mixing these two?

Comment: ```Invoices``` are used to collect one-time payments by sending them to clients through emails.

Comment: Kindly state what do you want to achieve here? Maybe someone suggests you a better solution.

Comment: When you create the Invoice, that invoice will automatically create a payment intent for the amount of the invoice. I don't know how to access it in Cashier but in Stripe's API you can access it as the `payment_intent` field on the Invoice. https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-payment_intent

Answer (score 1):

**Invoices can be paid in two ways**

> Stripe automatically creates and then attempts to collect payment on
> invoices for customers on subscriptions according to your
> subscriptions settings. However, if you’d like to attempt payment on
> an invoice out of the normal collection schedule or for some other
> reason, you can do so as follows.

```
$this->stripe->invoices->finalizeInvoice(
  $invoice->id,
  []
);
$this->stripe->invoices->pay(
   $invoice->id,
   []
);
```

**OR**

> You can manually send an invoice through email to your customer to
> pay. You can do so as follow

```
$this->stripe->invoices->finalizeInvoice(
  $invoice->id,
  []
);
$this->stripe->invoices->sendInvoice(
   $invoice->id,
   []
);
```